# Evaluating the definite integral of $\cot^2(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given that:
$$\cot(t) \to \infty \text{ when } t=0$$
and:
$$\int \cot^2(t) dt = -\cot(t) -t +C$$

It seems strange that:

$$\left[-\cot(t)-(t)\right]^{\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{\pi}{2}} = (-\cot^2(\pi+
\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right))-(\pi+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)))-(-\cot^2(\frac{\pi}{2})-(\frac{\pi}{2})) = \pi$$

since there as an asymptote in the middle of the area. Would somebody be able to identify my mistake? Even just a reference for me to read would be very much appreciated.
I am no mathematician, apologies!

Comment: Since you are integrating between $\pi$ and $\pi+\frac\pi2$, what has the behaviour of $\cot$ at $0$ to do with this?

Comment: I was surprised it evaluated to a finite number. I would expect the asymptote would lead to an infinite area. Also, surely the curve isn't differentiable at $\cot^2(0)$, so it seemed surprising the integration works at all. Could you not approximate the asymptote as an infinitely tall thin triangle, having an area tending to infinity?

Comment: First, what Jose Carlos wrote. Second, what you wrote after "it seems strange..." doesn't seem to make much sense: what is the leftmost expression? That seems to be the primitive of something, yet that function is the one you want to integrate...Finally, there is *no* asymptote "in the middle. THere is just one at the left extreme point of integration $\;\pi\;$ ...and that's all.

Comment: Sorry, I made this far more complicated by making a mess of the expression. I was rushing. I have corrected them now.

Comment: @JamesIzzard By $\left[\cot^2(t)\right]^{\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ you probably mean $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cot^2(t)dt$ or $\left[-\cot(t) -t\right]^{\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$. Do you?

Comment: @RobertZ Sorry! Yes I mean the former of your suggestions

Comment: No, According to the right side you should write $\left[-\cot(t) -t\right]^{\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus breaks if there is a singularity in the integration interval.

Check the conditions of application: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements.

Answer (score 3):

Note that it should be
$$\int \cot^2(t) dt =\int \frac{1-\sin^2(t)}{\sin^2(t)} dt=\int \left(\frac{1}{\sin^2(t)}-1\right) dt =-\cot(t)-t +C.$$
This primitive can be applied to intervals $I$ which have not any $k\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ as interior point.

Since $\lim_{t\to (k\pi)^{\pm}}\cot(t)=\mp\infty$, it follows that
$$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi^-} \cot^2(t) dt=\left[-\cot(t)-t\right]_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi^-}=+\infty$$
and
$$\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2} \cot^2(t) dt=\left[-\cot(t)-t\right]^{\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\pi^+}=-\infty.$$
The function $\cot^2(x)$ is not integrable over $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ (for a similar reason $1/x$ is not integrable over $[-1,1]$).

Comment: Typo's corrected. Thankyou.

Comment: Also note that when Robert is writing something of the form $\int_a^{b^-} f(x) dx$ he means $lim_{x \to b^-} \int_{a}^{x} f(x) dx$. Since $f$ is integrable over every Intervall $(a,x)$ for $x < b$, you can evaluate the integral and then take the limit to arrive at the answer Robert gave, $\infty$.